# Ajax Issue (possibly due to encodeURIComponent characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that has a textarea that users enter data into and then submit the form via ajax to the same page where it is then processed.

Every once in a while a user will enter some data that will throw an ajax error.

I stripped away all the other form fields and narrowed it down to the textarea that is causing the problem, but I can't find out why.

I built a sample page that I keep running to debug the problem, but I can't figure out why I am getting the problem.

I tried to create a fiddle and was having issues :(

Here is a link to the test page: https://fundraising-matrix.com/greenpill/broken.php

Here is the code of the test page (broken.php):

```
<?php
if (!$_POST) { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitEncodeURI() {

      //including other form data that I stripped away
      var dataString = 'formid=completeActivity&submit=submit&uid=5435716e20463&notificationcounter=0';

      //grab and encode the textarea text
      var txtValue = encodeURIComponent($('#test_textarea').val());

      //add the textarea text to my string
      dataString += '&dispo='+txtValue;

      //submit the data to itself
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'broken.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(returnData) {
          $('#encodedTextArea').html(returnData);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Failed');
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
  <p><strong>Sample Failing Text:</strong><br /><br />
    test please ignore 5105 = 33 5128 = 12 5325 = 19 6790 = 8 6791 = 4 6792 = 8 7125 = 20 7141 = 1
  </p>
  <textarea id="test_textarea" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></textarea><input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="submitEncodeURI();">
  <br />
  <strong>Submitted Text:</strong><br />
  <div id="encodedTextArea"></div>
<?php
}
else {
  echo $_POST['dispo'];
}
?>
```

**What Doesn't Work**

When I enter:
"test please ignore 5105 = 33 5128 = 12 5325 = 19 6790 = 8 6791 = 4 6792 = 8 7125 = 20 7141 = 1"
into the textarea, ajax will fail due to a "500 Internal Server Error".

**What Does Work**

When I change the last character to anything besides a "1", it works.

Example: "test please ignore 5105 = 33 5128 = 12 5325 = 19 6790 = 8 6791 = 4 6792 = 8 7125 = 20 7141 = 2"

**Why does changing the last character all of a sudden allow the ajax to work? And why is it breaking (returning a 500 internal server error) in the first place?**

I think it has to do with some combination of the `encodeURIComponent()` characters.

Comment: im not sure, but with ajax you can sent the data with this format: {var_one:value,var_two:value} try with this, and in the PHP or Server side you get the data with $_POST["var_one"], may be this can help you

Comment: check your server logs for more info on the error occured. error logs will tell you what really happened.

Comment: In my server is working, put a try catch between you **echo $_POST['dispo'];**

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it! I tried the alternative way of submitting ajax, I didn't get any difference in results. I don't have anything in my error logs showing up for this issue :( I tried adding the "try/catch", however, it never makes it back to the server as it bombs out during ajax as it for some reason can't find the page (when submitting with the "1" at the end, the "What Does Work" still submits fine)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours, I finally figured it out.

Here is why when testing the sample text "test please ignore 5105 = 33 5128 = 12 5325 = 19 6790 = 8 6791 = 4 6792 = 8 7125 = 20 7141 = 1" on other's servers it may work and when testing it on mine, it will not work.

My server has many safeguards in place that prevent against sql injection attacks. If it detects any form of these attacks it throws it out the request to the server.

If you look at the string I was trying to send the start of it has "ignore" and the very last characters of the string are "7141 = 1".

My server detects "or" within the string "ignore" and "1 = 1" within the string "7141 = 1". When my server detects anywhere within a string "or 1 = 1", it recognizes this as a possible sql injection attack and kills the request to the server.

This is why "test please ignore 5105 = 33 5128 = 12 5325 = 19 6790 = 8 6791 = 4 6792 = 8 7125 = 20 7141 = 2" would work, because it no longer finds "or 1 = 1".

This little issue cost me many hours...